# Subquery for calculated field giving invalid argument to function error

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a table with a list of stores and attributes that dictate the age of the store in weeks and the order volume of the store. The second table lists the UPLH goals based on age and volume. I want to return the stores listed in the first table along with its associated UPLH goal. The following works correctly:

```
        SELECT store, weeksOpen, totalItems, 
    (
    SELECT max(UPLH)
    FROM uplhGoals as b
    WHERE b.weeks <= a.weeksOpen AND 17000 between b.vMIn and b.vmax
    ) as UPLHGoal
    FROM weekSpecificUPLH as

 a
```

But this query, which is replacing the hard coded value of totalItems with the field from the first table, gives me the "Invalid argument to function" error.

```
SELECT store, weeksOpen, totalItems, 
(
SELECT max(UPLH)
FROM uplhGoals as b
WHERE b.weeks <= a.weeksOpen AND a.totalItems between b.vMIn and b.vmax
) as UPLHGoal
FROM weekSpecificUPLH as a
```

Any ideas why this doesnt work? Are there any other options? I can easily use a dmax() and cycle through every record to create a new table but that seems the long way around something that a query should be able to produce.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e123a8/1
It appears that SQLFiddle output (below) was what i was looking for even though Access gives the error.

```
| store | weeksOpen | totalItems | UPLHGoal |
|-------|-----------|------------|----------|
|     1 |        15 |      13000 |       30 |
|     2 |        37 |       4000 |       20 |
|     3 |        60 |      10000 |       30 |
```

EDIT:

weekSpecificUPLH is a query not a table. If I create a new test table in Access, with identical fields, it works. This would indicate to me that it has something to do with the [totalItems] field which is actually a calculated result. So instead i replace that field with [a.IPO * a.OPW]. Same error. Its as if its not treating it as the correct type of number.

Ive tried:

```
SELECT store, weeksOpen, (opw * ipo) as totalItems, 
(
SELECT max(UPLH)
FROM uplhGoals as b
WHERE 17000 between b.vMIn and b.vmax AND b.weeks <= a.weeksOpen
) as UPLHGoal
FROM weekSpecificUPLH as
a
```

which works. but replace the '17000' with 'totalitems' and same error. I even tried using val(totalItems) to no avail.

Comment: Does the error message say which function is getting the invalid argument?

Comment: The only function I see is `MAX()`, and you have the same argument in both versions.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @barmar it does not give any additional information.  Everything is identical in both except for using a field rather than a static value. I'll do that and post the link.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS-Access? You have both tags.

Comment: This is in MS-Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was changing the type of value of totalItems. To solve I:

- Copied the weekSpecificUPLH query results to a new table 'tempUPLH'
- Used that table in place of the query which correctly pulled the UPLHGoal from the 'uplhGoals' table

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn it into

```
b.vmin < a.totalItems AND b.vmax > a.totalItems
```

Although there're questions to your DB design.
For future approaches, it would be very helpful if you reveal your DB structure.

For example, it seems you don't have the records in weekSpecificUPLH table related to the records in UPLHGoals table, do you?

Or, more general: these table are not related in any way except for rules described by data itself in Goals table (which is "external" to DB model).

Thus, when you call it "associated" you got yourself & others into confusion, I presume, because everyone immediately start considering the classical Relation in terms of Relational Model.

Comment: Your correct, they aren't related in DB terms, sorrry for the misunderstanding. I tried that method which resulted in the same error. If you were to replace a.totalItems with a static value (e.g., 13200) it would return the correct result similar to my first example.

Comment: But your initial code works in SQLFiddle as well - try it.

It is legit.

PS while the query with join is syntactiacally legit too - it's very wrong conceptually: there's nothing to join between these tables, as they're unrelated.

Remembering that SQL is declarative, thus the engine totally defines how to interpret what you declare and turns it into particular actions - I'd opt for more straightforward query with kind of a "closure" you're done initially

although, anyway - the execution plan is what should decide here

Comment: This solution, in Access, returned the same error as the original.

Comment: so why were you fooling us with "mysql" tag, for god's sake?! :-\